# Why does an sbt project with ScalaVersion set to a 2.11 load 2.10 as well

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatra

Following is the core of the `project/build.sbt` for a scalatra/spark project :

```
  val ScalaVersion = "2.11.6"
  val ScalatraVersion = "2.4.0-RC2-2"

//   ivyScala := ivyScala.value map { _.copy(overrideScalaVersion = true)}
  lazy val project = Project (
    "keywordsservlet",
    file("."),
    settings = ScalatraPlugin.scalatraSettings ++ scalateSettings ++ Seq(
      organization := Organization,
      name := Name,
      version := Version,
      scalaVersion := ScalaVersion,
      resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases,
      resolvers += "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases",
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
//        "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % ScalaVersion,
        "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.4.1",
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalate" % ScalatraVersion,
        "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-specs2" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
        "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2" % "runtime",
        "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.2.10.v20150310" % "container",
        "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
      ),
```

Here is the sbt output: notice it is loading a 2.10 target !

```
$ sbt   

[info] Loading project definition from /shared/keywords/project
[info] Updating {file:/shared/keywords/project/}keywords-build...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /shared/keywords/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[info] Set current project to KeywordsServlet (in build file:/shared/keywords/)
```

So what is happening here?

Comment: sbt is using 2.10 for itself maybe? http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Community/ChangeSummary_0.13.0.html

Comment: Yes you are correct - i have accepted an answer stating as much .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between the version of Scala that you are using for your project and the version of Scala that sbt itself uses.

sbt 0.13 can compile 2.9, 2.10 and 2.11 (and 2.12). However, when it compiles your build.sbt or Build.scala files, sbt 0.13 uses Scala 2.10.

Similarly, all of the plugins that sbt uses are compiled with 2.10.

On the other hand, sbt 0.12 used Scala 2.9.

Comment: Ah!  I was worried because there is a scala-reflect.jar versioning mismatch occurrding in my scalatra/spark project.  Trying to track down carefully the potential sources of conflict: now that's one less!